# Can't pass UIButton image with viewWithTag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't understand why I'm getting "[UIScrollView imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
    for (int i=0;i<[imagesForGame count];i++)
        {      
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(i*310, 0, 310, 200);
            [button setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imagesForGame objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openFullPic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [_myScroller addSubview:button];
        }


    -(void)openFullPic:(UIButton *)sender
    {

        UIButton *random = (UIButton *)[_myScroller viewWithTag:sender.tag];
        UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
        test.image = random.imageView.image; // <-- Error
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender will be a button anyway, so use it instead.

```
-(void)openFullPic:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIButton *random = (UIButton *)sender;
    UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    test.image = random.imageView.image; // <-- No more error.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you never set the tag for the button.
Do in the first loop, button.tag = i;

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that! Thanks

Comment: Why is my answer not ticked as correct then? :)
EDIT: ah I see now that the other answer is also good. My answer however did exactly answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have `UIButton`s instance in `sender` variable so you don't need to use `viewWithTag` at all ;-)